# CarrierWave: not saving image (only tmp)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, carrierwave

I have problem with CarrierWave. Images and path in database are not saved but tmp files are.

Here's my AvatarUploader (apps/uploaders/avatar_uploader.rb):

```
# encoding: utf-8

class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

# Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
# include CarrierWave::RMagick
include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

# Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
storage :file
# storage :fog

# Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
# This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
def store_dir
  "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
end

# Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
# def default_url
#   "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
# end

# Process files as they are uploaded:
# process :scale => [200, 300]
#
# def scale(width, height)
#   # do something
# end

# Create different versions of your uploaded files:
# version :thumb do
#   process :scale => [50, 50]
# end

# Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
# For images you might use something like this:
def extension_white_list
  %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
end

# Override the filename of the uploaded files:
# Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
# def filename
#   "something.jpg" if original_filename
# end

end
```

And here's Member model (apps/models/member.rb):

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base

    attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :avatar

    mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader

    email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

    validates :name, presence: true,
                                     uniqueness: true,
                                     length: { within: 4..32 }
    validates :email, presence: true,
                                        uniqueness: true,
                                        format: { with: email_regex }
    validates :password, presence: true,
                                             length: { minimum: 6 }

    has_secure_password

    before_create :generate_token

    private

        def generate_token
            begin
                self.auth_token = SecureRandom.hex(16)
            end while Member.exists?(auth_token: self.auth_token)
        end

end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: One CW's ActiveRecord support is installed, and you have added the `avatar` string column, you still need to save your member with the cached version of the file.  See the ActiveRecord part of https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave.  Just a guess, since I don't see anywhere in your posted code that you do that.  Otherwise, it looks fine to me.

Comment: I don't have any idea how to repair it :(

Comment: Try walking through the steps shown in the ReadMe associated with the GitHub link I provided above (scroll down).  There are a lot of small set-up steps required.  I strongly recommend with CarrierWave that you read through the code to know what it is doing; it's a powerful gem that does a lot of work.  If you need more help, edit your post to include the controller code that eventually saves the `Member` record; this is the point at which the cached version of the file is written to the store, the database is updated with the name and most of the other magic occurs.

Comment: Thanks for help, but I just created new project, copied controller, model, views and it's work! Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used `has_secure_password` for Member model. In edit form I forgot to add password and password_confirmation to authenticate user.

Stupid mistake.